# How to write a function that is automatically called when a contract receives an ERC20 token?

Tags: erc-20, fallback-function, address.transfer

Fallback functions only work when a contract receives ether. Is there a way to write a fallback-style function that is automatically called when a contract receives an ERC20 token?

Answer (score 2):

There is a reference implementation in [EIP 677](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/677)  and also in [ERC223](https://medium.com/kinfoundation/the-new-erc223-token-standard-8dddbf1a5909)

This function must transfer tokens and invoke the function `tokenFallback (address, uint256, bytes`) in `_to`, if `_to` is a contract.

The token fallback function, which will be called at the receiver contract, must be named tokenFallback and take the parameters:(address, uint256, bytes). It’s an analogue of the fallback function for ETH transactions and should be used to handle incoming transactions.